# How to hide modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal

How can I hide a modal if I clicked outside the modal?

Is it like this?

```
.show_player {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 530px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.show_player:target {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event is managed with JavaScript, not CSS.

This should be already the default behavior of your modal if you have the `.modal-backdrop` class on the outside element.
See this for more details : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Alternatively you can manage this behavior with the backdrop option :

```
data-backdrop="true"
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

If it's not working, check that you've correctly added the bootstrap javascript to your page :

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or show your code